# Integral, set and parametric representation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am to compute the following: $\displaystyle\iiint\limits_V 1\, dx\, dy\, dz$,

where $V= \{{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : (x-z)^2 +4y^2 < (1-z)^2} \text{ and } 0<z<1\}.$

Does anyone have idea what parametric representation should I take? I think there will be something elliptic, for instance $y=\frac{1}{2}r\sin(\alpha)$ and $z=z$, but I don't know what about $x$. Or maybe another parametric representation? Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
$$
u=x-z\quad
v=2y\quad
w=1-z
$$
New domain will be $\{(u,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^3:u^2+v^2<w^2, 0<w<1\}$. Jacobian is also easy to compute.